# MySQL/node.js transactions within a stored procedure intermix

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures, transactions

I am using a single MySQL client for multiple HTTP requests in node.js. So if I run transactions the queries could probably intermix. For example the first page request runs a transaction on the MySQL client and the second page request calls the same transaction on the same client but arrives before the transaction of the first request has been committed (or rolled back).

A solution could be to use node-mysql-queues (https://github.com/bminer/node-mysql-queues).

However, I have been thinking that I could wrap the transactions into stored procedures. So my question is: Can queries in a stored procedure intermix too if I am calling them on the same client directly successively (like described above)?

Greetings
Max